# Cybersource payment gateway Authentication error in production environment

Tags: php, cybersource

I have tested the Cybersource payment  in testing environment and it was successful.am using soap toolkit.

my working code is 
https://notepad.pw/3i26r0sh

this code is working for testing environment. For the production environment i have changed the $url to "https://ics2wsa.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.53.wsdl"

but it returns authentication error

what other changes need to make in above code for production environment?

Comment: Test and production have different security credentials. Did you use different credentials for production?

Comment: No .let me try.